# How to use sched_yield() properly?

Tags: c, pthreads

For an assignment, I need to use `sched_yield()` to synchronize threads. I understand a mutex lock/conditional variables would be much more effective, but I am not allowed to use those.

The only functions we are allowed to use are `sched_yield()`, `pthread_create()`, and `pthread_join()`. We cannot use mutexes, locks, semaphores, or any type of shared variable.

I know `sched_yield()` is supposed to relinquish access to the thread so another thread can run. So it should move the thread it executes on to the back of the running queue.

The code below is supposed to print 'abc' in order and then the newline after all three threads have executed. I looped `sched_yield()` in functions `b()` and `c()` because it wasn't working as I expected, but I'm pretty sure all that is doing is delaying the printing because a function is running so many times, not because `sched_yield()` is working.

The server it needs to run on has 16 CPUs. I saw somewhere that `sched_yield()` may immediately assign the thread to a new CPU.

Essentially I'm unsure of how, using only `sched_yield()`, to synchronize these threads given everything I could find and troubleshoot with online.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sched.h>

void* a(void*);
void* b(void*);
void* c(void*);

int main( void ){
    pthread_t a_id, b_id, c_id;
    pthread_create(&a_id, NULL, a, NULL);
    pthread_create(&b_id, NULL, b, NULL);
    pthread_create(&c_id, NULL, c, NULL);

    pthread_join(a_id, NULL);
    pthread_join(b_id, NULL);
    pthread_join(c_id, NULL);

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

void* a(void* ret){
    printf("a");
    return ret;
}

void* b(void* ret){
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        sched_yield();
    }
    printf("b");
    return ret;
}

void* c(void* ret){
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        sched_yield();
    }
    printf("c");
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Unless you're using a real time scheduler algorithm for your threads/processes, `sched_yield()` is unspecified as the man page says. Start with setting up an appropriate scheduler so you can get predictable behavior from yielding.

Comment: @Shawn how would one go about that? We were told to just add threads and sync them, so I wasn't aware that it would get much more complicated

Comment: Assuming you're using Linux, start with https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html

Comment: If you were told to use `sched_yield()` without any earlier discussion about scheduling algorithms and which ones it works with, it doesn't speak well for the quality of your class or instructor.

Comment: As its name indicates, `sched_yield()` is about thread *scheduling*, not synchronization.  It is not a proper substitute for synchronization objects such as mutexes.

Comment: @Shawn, [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sched_yield.html) does not qualify its description of the behavior of `sched_yield()` on what scheduler is in use, and the OP did not tag a specific OS.  On the other hand, inasmuch as Linux is the most likely platform for the assignment, and as other systems may also add their own qualifications, not to mention that `sched_yield()` is the wrong tool for the job, I am inclined to agree that the assignment as described is flawed.

Comment: 'For an assignment, I need to use sched_yield() to synchronize threads'.....yeah, you are stuft, right there:(

Comment: @JohnBollinger I was honestly confused at the assignment because we had already worked on thread synchronization with monitors and semaphores and did not cover scheduling at all

Comment: On Linux sched_yield with SCHED_OTHER (ie normal processes) is not a good thing to use. It puts the thread at the very end of *all* process and thread priorities. Not just the threads in the process. Yes, even the nice 20 threads get to run before a yielded thread. And in your case there are plenty of available CPU cores so it gets bumped off and immediately rescheduled. In fact if it is the only thread on a core it never stops running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's 4 cases:

a) the scheduler doesn't use multiplexing (e.g. doesn't use "round robin" but uses "highest priority thread that can run does run", or "earliest deadline first", or ...) and `sched_yield()` does nothing.

b) the scheduler does use multiplexing in theory, but you have more CPUs than threads so the multiplexing doesn't actually happen, and `sched_yield()` does nothing. *Note: With 16 CPUs and 2 threads, this is likely what you'd get for "default scheduling policy" on an OS like Linux - the `sched_yield()` just does a "Hrm, no other thread I could use this CPU for, so I guess the calling thread can keep using the same CPU!").*

c) the scheduler does use multiplexing and there's more threads than CPUs, but to improve performance (avoid task switches) the scheduler designer decided that `sched_yield()` does nothing.

d)  `sched_yield()` does cause a task switch (yielding the CPU to some other task), but that is not enough to do any kind of synchronization on its own (e.g. you'd need an atomic variable or something for the actual synchronization - maybe like "`while( atomic_variable_not_set_by_other_thread ) { sched_yield(); }`). Note that with an atomic variable (introduced in C11) it'd work without `sched_yield()` - the `sched_yield()` (if it does anything) merely makes busy waiting less awful/wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

> Essentially I'm unsure of how, using only `sched_yield()`, to
> synchronize these threads given everything I could find and
> troubleshoot with online.

That would be because `sched_yield()` is not well suited to the task.  As I wrote in comments, `sched_yield()` is about scheduling, not synchronization.  There is a relationship between the two, in the sense that synchronization events affect which threads are eligible to run, but that goes in the wrong direction for your needs.

You are probably looking at the problem from the wrong end.  You need each of your threads to wait to execute until it is their turn, and for them to do that, they need some mechanism to convey information among them about whose turn it is.  There are several alternatives for that, but if "only `sched_yield()`" is taken to mean that no library functions other than `sched_yield()` may be used for that purpose then a shared variable seems the expected choice.  The starting point should therefore be how you could use a shared variable to make the threads take turns in the appropriate order.

### Flawed starting point

Here is a naive approach that might spring immediately to mind:

```
/* FLAWED */
void *b(void *data){
    char *whose_turn = data;

    while (*whose_turn != 'b') {
        // nothing?
    }

    printf("b");
    *whose_turn = 'c';

    return NULL;
}
```

That is, the thread executes a busy loop, monitoring the shared variable to await it taking a value signifying that the thread should proceed.  When it has done its work, the thread modifies the variable to indicate that the next thread may proceed.  But there are several problems with that, among them:

1. Supposing that at least one other thread writes to the object designated by `*whose_turn`, the program contains a data race, and therefore its behavior is undefined.  As a practical matter, a thread that once entered the body of the loop in that function might loop infinitely, notwithstanding any action by other threads.
2. Without making additional assumptions about thread scheduling, such as a fairness policy, it is not safe to assume that the thread that will make the needed modification to the shared variable will be scheduled in bounded time.
3. While a thread is executing the loop in that function, it prevents any other thread from executing on the same core, yet it cannot make progress until some other thread takes action.  To the extent that we can assume preemptive thread scheduling, this is an efficiency issue and contributory to (2).  However, if we assume neither preemptive thread scheduling nor the threads being scheduled each on a separate core then this is an invitation to deadlock.

### Possible improvements

The conventional and most appropriate way to do that in a pthreads program is with the use of a mutex and condition variable.  Properly implemented, that resolves the data race (issue 1) and it ensures that other threads get a chance to run (issue 3).  If that leaves no other threads eligible to run besides the one that will modify the shared variable then it also addresses issue 2, to the extent that the scheduler is assumed to grant any CPU to the process at all.

But you are forbidden to do that, so what else is available? Well, you could make the shared variable `_Atomic`.  That would resolve the data race, and in practice it would likely be sufficient for the wanted thread ordering.  In principle, however, it does not resolve issue 3, and as a practical matter, it does not use `sched_yield()`.  Also, all that busy-looping is wasteful.

But wait! You have a clue in that you are told to use `sched_yield()`.  What could that do for you?  Suppose you insert a call to `sched_yield()` in the body of the busy loop:

```
/* (A bit) better */
void* b(void *data){
    char *whose_turn = data;

    while (*whose_turn != 'b') {
        sched_yield();
    }

    printf("b");
    *whose_turn = 'c';

    return NULL;
}
```

That resolves issues 2 and 3, explicitly affording the possibility for other threads to run and putting the calling thread at the tail of the scheduler's thread list.  Formally, it does not resolve issue 1 because `sched_yield()` has no documented effect on memory ordering, but in practice, I don't think it can be implemented without a (full) memory barrier.  If you are allowed to use atomic objects then combining an atomic shared variable with `sched_yield()` would tick all three boxes.  Even then, however, there would still be a bunch of wasteful busy-looping.

### Final remarks

Note well that `pthread_join()` is a synchronization function, thus, as I understand the task, you may not use it to ensure that the main thread's output is printed last.

Note also that I have not spoken to how the `main()` function would need to be modified to support the approach I have suggested.  Changes would be needed for that, and they are left as an exercise.

Comment: I updated requirements for clarity. `pthread_join` and `pthread_create` were explicitly allowed, but in my understanding they were not relevant to the specific problem I was having

Comment: @kdezra: So you're saying that you can create a thread for `a` and use `pthread_join()` to wait for it to finish; then create a thread for `b` and use `pthread_join()` to wait for it to finish; then ...? That would be the least insane possibility (a way to add the least overhead to a completely sequential program that should not be using threads at all).

Comment: @Brendan The only way we were allowed to create a sequential order was through `sched_yield()`. The assignment would have been extremely easy if we could have just run the threads individually.

Comment: @kdezra: In that case; I'd check if you're meant to assume there's only 1 CPU (and/or meant to pin your process to one specific CPU). Failing that; I'd ask your supervisor/lecturer to review comments to your question here on Stackoverflow (in case the question was flawed - lecturers are human and make mistakes sometimes).